# Emberjs: Redirect to last state a user was in using the router

Tags: redirect, ember.js, state, ember-old-router

I'd like to redirect the router to the last state a user was in.

What's the best way to do this? Is it possible to use redirectTo in the router somehow?

Here's an example. Suppose there are two main routes for a post, `show` and `edit`

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({

   post: Ember.Route.extend({         
       route: '/:post',

       show: Ember.Route.extend({
           route: '/',
           connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
              router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet("showPost", post);
           }
        }),

       edit: Ember.Route.extend({
           route: '/edit',
           connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
              router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet("editPost", post);
           }
        })

     })
  })
```

Now, I'd like to do something like:

```
    post: Ember.Route.extend({
       initialState: 'edit',
       route: '/:post',
       redirectTo: function(router) {
          router.transitionTo(router.currentState.name)
       }.property()
    })
```

Additional complication:
The redirectTo is specific to a given post, i.e., post/3 may default to `edit`, but post/4 may default to `show` depending on their last respective states.

I'm guessing the other way to do this is in by using a parent controller / view that has it's own stateManager, and navigates to the appropriate child view. If that's the preferred method, what's wrong with using the router for this?

Any clarity here is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

On every route transition you could store the last route in a cookie. You could do this by making all your routes inherit from an abstract route object and adding the code into the willTransition action hook.

Then all that remains it to add some code on the main index route that loads the data from the cookie and then transitions to the saved route.

Make sure you record the ember route name rather than just the URL and any extraneous data associated.

If you're going to also deal with save state (ie unfinished record updates and the like) then you might want to use the local storage to store unfinished edits, etc.

In the past when I've dealt with such things, it's very easy to get into semi-infinite loops, so I'd definitely make sure you give them the option to restore or something rather than making it automatic.